# JSP and server side latency

Tags: java, performance, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

I am using Spring MVC, and have a general question regarding jsp files processing and server side latency. By server side latency I mean time of my Controller execution: from the beginning of my `execute()` method and till the time when the Model and View returned, e.g:
`return new ModelAndView(myModel,"myView.jsp");`

My question is: can adding of a few more elements to `myView.jsp` (one of the elements is the image, url of which is passed from the myModel) affect the latency of the request? To be clear: nothing was changed in the Controller itself, the changed was made in .jsp only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that JSP is rendered into HTML on the server side. If you look at the implementation, they are compiled into servlets with a bunch of println statements.

So yes, adding elements to the JSP can definitely affect the latency of the request.